# Two Sample test for two samples with different distribution

Tags: nonparametric, two-sample

I have independent random samples of $R^d, d>1$ $X=\{X_1,..X_n\}$ and $Y=\{Y_1,.. Y_n\}$ with respective distributions $F_1$ and $F_2$. In a regular two sample problem we test $H_0:F_1=F_2$ vs $H_1:F_1\neq F_2$.
If we know that $F_1\neq F_2$, can we make a variation of the two sample test that tests how close are the theoretical distributions $F_1, F_2$ *given* The random samples $X,Y$? Since we know that $F_1\neq F_2$ we cannot ask if the distributions are same, but even for different distributions $F_1, F_2$ it is possible that $X=Y$ since we have a finite number of samples. This is somewhat similar to aliasing in signal processing, but I am not sure how to formulate it. I make calculations that are only based on $X$ and $Y$ so I want to use some test to determine their similarity with some confidence $1- \alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by "How close" ? what metric do you want to use ?

Comment: I am looking for a statistical test that will determine if $X$ and $Y$ are similar in the same way I saw in different two sample tests - by applying function to the measurements and calculating the test statistic.